# Ans key is showing up but no calculations work with it

Tags: jquery, html

for my code the ans key is supposed to take the last entered number (not calculation). This works, however when you try to do it with any calculations, the ans key doesn't work. I'm using a global variable for ans and updating the value of it after every function. The ans essentially act as 0, when it's supposed to act as the value of it's text. This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style>
            .threadbit .thread {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .divTable {
                display: table;
                width: 20%;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .divTableRow {
                display: table-row;
            }

            .divTableCell,
            .divTableHead {
                border: 1px solid #999999;
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 3px 10px;
            }

            .divTableBody {
                display: table-row-group;
            }

            button {
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 1.1em;
                font-size: 1.1em;
                border-color: white;
            }

            #input {
                text-align: right;
            }

        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var result;
                var anss;
                var memory = 0;
                $("#input").prop("disabled", true);

                $(".parseFloat").click(function() {
                    var text = $('#input').val();
                    if (text != "0") {
                        var value1 = text;
                        var ButtonVal = $(this);
                        var value2 = ButtonVal.val();
                        if (value2 != '.' || value1.indexOf('.') == -1) {
                            var inputfield = value1 + value2;
                            $('#input').val(inputfield);
                            anss = inputfield
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#input').val();
                    }
                });
                $(document).unbind('keypress').bind('keypress', function(e) {
                    var text1 = $('#input').val();
                    var text3 = text1;

                    if (e.keyCode == 48) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "0"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield


                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 49) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "1"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 50) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "2"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 51) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "3"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 52) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "4"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 53) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "5"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 54) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "6"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 55) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "7"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 56) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "8"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 57) {
                        var inputfield = text3 + "9"
                        $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 110) {
                        if ($('#input').val().indexOf('.') == -1) {
                            var inputfield = text3 + "."
                            $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        }
                        anss = inputfield

                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 190) {
                        if ($('#input').val().indexOf('.') == -1) {
                            var inputfield = text3 + "."
                            $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        }
                        anss = inputfield


                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
                        if ($('#input').val().indexOf('.') == -1) {
                            var inputfield = text3 + "."
                            $('#input').val(inputfield);
                        }
                        anss = inputfield


                    }
                });
                $("#plus").click(function() {
                    var storeparseFloat = $('#input').text();
                    $('#input').val('');
                    $(".parseFloat").click(function() {
                        var storeparseFloat1 = $('#input').val();
                        var ok1 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat)
                        var ok2 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat1)

                        var result = ok1 + ok2
                        $("#equal").click(function() {
                            $('#input').val(result);
                            anss = result

                        });
                    });
                });
                $("#subtract").click(function() {
                    var storeparseFloat = $('#input').val();
                    $('#input').val('');
                    $(".parseFloat").click(function() {
                        var storeparseFloat1 = $('#input').val();
                        var ok1 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat)
                        var ok2 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat1)

                        var result = ok1 - ok2
                        $("#equal").click(function() {
                            $('#input').val(result);
                            anss = result


                        });
                    });
                });
                $("#multiply").click(function() {
                    var storeparseFloat = $('#input').val();
                    $('#input').val('');
                    $(".parseFloat").click(function() {
                        var storeparseFloat1 = $('#input').val();
                        var ok1 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat)
                        var ok2 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat1)

                        var result = ok1 * ok2
                        $("#equal").click(function() {
                            $('#input').val(result);
                            anss = result


                        });
                    });
                });
                $("#division").click(function() {
                    var storeparseFloat = $('#input').val();
                    $('#input').val('');
                    $(".parseFloat").click(function() {
                        var storeparseFloat1 = $('#input').val();
                        var ok1 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat)
                        var ok2 = parseFloat(storeparseFloat1)

                        var result = ok1 / ok2
                        $("#equal").click(function() {
                            $('#input').val(result);
                            anss = result

                        });
                    });
                });
                $("#mminus").click(function() {
                    var warmth = $('#input').val();
                    memory = parseFloat(memory) - parseFloat(warmth);
                    $('#input').val('');
                    return memory;
                    anss = memory
                });
                $("#mplus").click(function() {
                    var warmth = $('#input').val();

                    memory = parseFloat(memory) + parseFloat(warmth);
                    $('#input').val('');
                    return memory;
                    anss = memory

                });
                $("#mr").click(function() {
                    $('#input').val(parseFloat((memory)));
                    anss = memory

                });
                $("#ac").click(function() {
                    window.location.reload()
                    anss = 0
                });
                $("#back").click(function() {
                    var inputt = $('#input').val().slice(0, -1);
                    var inputt1 = parseFloat(inputt)
                    $('#input').val(inputt1);
                    anss = inputt1
                });
                $("#zip").click(function() {
                    var comfort = $('#input').val();
                    var comfort2 = parseFloat(comfort)

                    var comfort1 = comfort2 * -1
                    $('#input').val(comfort1);
                    anss = comfort1

                });
                $("#exp").click(function() {
                    var comfort = $('#input').val();
                    var comfort2 = parseFloat(comfort)

                    var comfort3 = Math.pow(10, comfort2)
                    $('#input').val(comfort3)
                    anss = comfort3
                });
                $("#rnd").click(function() {
                    var comfort = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

                    $('#input').val(comfort)
                    anss = comfort
                });
                $("#ans").click(function() {
                    $('#input').val(anss)
                    var aaa = $(anss).text()
                    $(anss).val(aaa)
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:404px;height:60px;font-size:20px;" id="input"><br>
        </form>
        <div class="divTable">
            <div class="divTableBody">
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">sin</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">cos</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">tan</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><input type="radio" name="mode" value="deg">Deg</div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><input type="radio" name="mode" value="rad">Rad</div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">sin<sup>-1</sup></button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">cos<sup>-1</sup></button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">tan<sup>-1</sup></button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">&pi;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">e</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">x<sup>y</sup></button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">x<sup>3</sup></button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">x<sup>2</sup></button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">e<sup>x</sup></button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">10<sup>x</sup></button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text"><sup>y</sup>&radic;x</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text"><sup>3</sup>&radic;x</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">&radic;x</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">In</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">log</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">&lpar;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">&rpar;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">1/x</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">&percnt;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text">n&excl;</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="7">7</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="8">8</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="9">9</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" value="plus" id="plus">&plus;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="back">Back</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="4">4</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="5">5</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="6">6</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" value="minus" id="subtract">&minus;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell" id="ans"><button type="text">Ans</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="1">1</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="2">2</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="3">3</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" value="*" id="multiply">&times;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="mplus">M+</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value="0">0</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button class="parseFloat" type="text" value=".">.</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="exp">EXP</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" value="/" id="division">&#xf7;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="mminus">M-</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="zip">&plusmn;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="rnd">RND</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="ac">AC</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="equal">&#61;</button></div>
                    <div class="divTableCell"><button type="text" id="mr">MR</button></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
    `

``
```

Comment: Code after `return` is not run.

Comment: I removed the return but it sitll didn't work.

Comment: There are lots of things wrong in this code, some more or less wrong depending on what you want to happen. For instance, you have `$("#division").click(function() {... $(".parseFloat").click(function () { ... $("#equal").click(function () { ... }); }); });`. That code does says: whenever `#division` is clicked, *add* a click event listener to all elements with the class `parseFloat`. Any existing event handlers will remain, including any added when `#division` was clicked previously. When elelemts with `parseFloat` are clicked, a click event will be added to `#equal`.... etc. Use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I am going to switch to using .one() so it unbounds the event handler after its first use.